# how to block drop function in mongodb?

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

MongoDB replication was created in AWS by using Ubuntu machines. I created a database in mongodb, but it was deleted in my office. Am I able to enable termination protection, that is "drop command not executed in my database"?

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom user role without dropping database or collection alowed:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.createRole/#mongodb-method-db.createRole